# Read a 'fake' xml document (xml fragment) in a XmlTextReader object

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

**[Case]**
I have reveived a bunch of 'xml files' with metadata about a big number of documents in them. At least, that was what I requested. What I received where 'xml files' without a root element, they are structured something like this (i left out a bunch of elements):

```
<folder name = "abc"></folder>
<folder name = "abc/def">
<document name = "ghi1">
</document>
<document name = "ghi2">
</document>
</folder>
```

**[Problem]**
When I try to read the file in an XmlTextReader object it fails telling me that there is no root element.

**[Current workaround]**
Of course I can read the file as a stream, append < xmlroot> and < /xmlroot> and write the stream to a new file and read that one in XmlTextReader. Which is exactly what I am doing now, but I prefer not to 'tamper' with the original data.

**[Requested solution]**
I understand that I should use XmlTextReader for this, with the DocumentFragment option. However, this gives the compiletime error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: XmlNodeType DocumentFragment is not supported
>   for partial content parsing. Line 1, position 1.

**[Faulty code]**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"C:\test.txt";
            XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(file, XmlNodeType.DocumentFragment, null);
            while(tr.Read())
                Debug.WriteLine("NodeType: {0} NodeName: {1}", tr.NodeType, tr.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using obsolete methods... XmlDataDocuments have been obsolete since .NET 4

Comment: Changed the question, using the XmlTextReader class now.

Comment: Actually XmlTextReader has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use XmlReader.Create instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip John. Always hard to get the nitty gritty of an existing program language without experience. It works. Posted the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `XmlReader` can be made to read the data using the `ConformanceLevel.Fragment` option as demonstrated by Martijn, it seems that `XmlDataDocument` does not like the idea of having multiple root elements.

I thought I'd try a different approach, much like the one you're currently using, but without the intermediate file. Most XML libraries (XmlDocument, XDocument, XmlDataDocument) can take a `TextReader` as an input, so I've implemented one of my own. It's used like so:

```
var dataDocument = new XmlDataDocument();
dataDocument.Load(new FakeRootStreamReader(File.OpenRead("test.xml")));
```

The code of the actual class:

```
public class FakeRootStreamReader : TextReader
{
    private static readonly char[] _rootStart;
    private static readonly char[] _rootEnd;

    private readonly TextReader _innerReader;
    private int _charsRead;
    private bool _eof;

    static FakeRootStreamReader()
    {
        _rootStart = "<root>".ToCharArray();
        _rootEnd = "</root>".ToCharArray();
    }

    public FakeRootStreamReader(Stream stream)
    {
        _innerReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    }

    public FakeRootStreamReader(TextReader innerReader)
    {
        _innerReader = innerReader;
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (!_eof && _charsRead < _rootStart.Length)
        {
            // Prepend root element
            return ReadFake(_rootStart, buffer, index, count);
        }

        if (!_eof)
        {
            // Normal reading operation
            int charsRead = _innerReader.Read(buffer, index, count);
            if (charsRead > 0) return charsRead;

            // We've reached the end of the Stream
            _eof = true;
            _charsRead = 0;
        }

        // Append root element end tag at the end of the Stream
        return ReadFake(_rootEnd, buffer, index, count);
    }

    private int ReadFake(char[] source, char[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int length = Math.Min(source.Length - _charsRead, count);
        Array.Copy(source, _charsRead, buffer, offset, length);
        _charsRead += length;
        return length;
    }
}
```

The first call to `Read(...)` will return only the `<root>` element. Subsequent calls read the stream as normal, until the end of the stream is reached, then the end tag is outputted.

The code is a bit... meh... mostly because I wanted to handle some never-gonna-happen cases where someone tries to read the stream less than 6 characters at a time.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"C:\test.txt";
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file, settings))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    Debug.WriteLine("NodeType: {0} NodeName: {1}", reader.NodeType, reader.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```