# Obtaining the XML encoding from an XML declaration fragment: XmlDeclaration is not supported for partial content parsing

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, encoding

I'm working on some code to read an XML fragment which contains an XML declaration, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and parse the encoding.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72fhddt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I should be able to do it like this:

```
var nt = new NameTable();
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
var context = new XmlParserContext(null, mgr, null, XmlSpace.None);

var reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>", 
    System.Xml.XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, context);
```

However, I'm getting a `System.Xml.XmlException` on the call to the `System.Xml.XmlTextReader` constructor with an error message:

> XmlNodeType XmlDeclaration is not supported for partial content
>   parsing.

I've googled this error in quotes -- exactly zero results found (edit: now there's one result: this post) -- and without quotes, which yields nothing useful.  I've also looked at [MSDN for the XmlNodeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and it doesn't say anything about it not being supported.

What am I missing here?  **How can I get an `XmlTextReader` instance from an XML declaration fragment**?

Note, **my goal here is just to determine the encoding of a partially-built XML document** where I'm making the assumption that it at least contains a declaration node; thus, I'm trying to get `reader.Encoding`.  If there's another way to do that, I'm open to that.

At present, I'm parsing the declaration manually using regex, which is not the best approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update: Getting the encoding from XML documentation or from XML fragment:**

Here's a way to get the encoding without having to resort to fake root, using [XmlReader.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private static string GetXmlEncoding(string xmlString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlString)) throw new ArgumentException("The provided string value is null or empty.");

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
        {
            if (!xmlReader.Read()) throw new ArgumentException(
                "The provided XML string does not contain enough data to be valid XML (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.read)");

            var result = xmlReader.GetAttribute("encoding");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output, with a full and fragment XML:

[image: XML encoding ith XmlReader.Create]

If you want to have System.Text.Encoding, you can modify the code to look like this:

```
    private static Encoding GetXmlEncoding(string xmlString)
    {
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };

            var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings);
            reader.Read();

            var encoding = reader.GetAttribute("encoding");

            var result = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Old answer:**

As you mentioned, [XmlTextReader's Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)-property contains the encoding.

Here's a full Console app's source code which hopefully is useful:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asciiXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ASCII""?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";
        var utf8XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";

        var asciiResult = GetXmlEncoding(asciiXML);
        var utfResult = GetXmlEncoding(utf8XML);

        Console.WriteLine(asciiResult);
        Console.WriteLine(utfResult);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static Encoding GetXmlEncoding(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));

        using (var xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            xmlreader.MoveToContent();
            var encoding = xmlreader.Encoding;

            return encoding;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output from the program:

[image: XML Encoding output]

If you know that the XML only contains the declaration, maybe you can add an empty root? So for example:

```
        var fragmentResult = GetXmlEncoding(xmlFragment + "<root/>");
```

[image: XML Fragment]

Comment: But will this work if I *only have* a declaration fragment, i.e. none of the rest of the XML body?  All I have is `<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ASCII""?>` for example.  From my question: "I'm working on some code to read an **XML fragment** which contains an XML declaration, e.g. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"

Comment: Yeah, see, I tried it, and I got "root element is missing"

Comment: Yeah, true. Not an ideal solution, but how about adding "fake" root? So for example: var xmlForEncodingParsing = xmlFragment + "<root>/<root>"

Comment: Adding a fake root may be the only option here.  Bummer.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out, but I updated my answer to show an example with a fake root.

Comment: Thank your for the comments. I decided to try once more and found out that you can actually do this without resorting to fake roots :) See the updated answer.

Comment: Nice!  I had actually stumbled across something similar to that ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040803/2704659)) but I was unable to get from that to the encoding.  The key, which you provided, is this: `reader.GetAttribute("encoding")`.

Comment: Can I suggest some edits to your code (see my edits)?  Feel free to roll back, but I noticed `XmlReader` is also disposable and thus amenable to use with a `using` statement.  I also added some validation logic as well.

Answer (score 5):

Good evening, here's the solution with a System.Text.Encoding as output. 
I made it to be clear, and step by step.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var line = File.ReadLines(YourFileName).First();
        var correctXml = line + "<Root></Root>";
        var xml = XDocument.Parse(correctXml);
        var stringEncoding = xml.Declaration.Encoding;
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(stringEncoding);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `xml.Declaration.Encoding` is a `string` not a `System.Text.Encoding`.  Can you add some code to get to that?

Comment: Hi roryap ! I updated the solution in order in to match your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late but you can use below code after loading it in a XmlDocument

```
    static string getEncoding(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        if (xml.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
        {
            return (xml.FirstChild as XmlDeclaration).Encoding;
        }
        return "utf-8";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a byte array as input, try something like this:

```
private Encoding getEncoding(byte[] data)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);
            doc.Load(reader);
            XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlDeclaration>().FirstOrDefault();
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(declaration.Encoding);
        }
```