# encoding xml for deserialization in c#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, deserialization

I have several xml files which I want do deserialize.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
var sr = new StreamReader(current_file, encoding, true);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
var i = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The problem is that the files have got different encodings. "Windows-1252" and "iso-8859-1". How can I deal with both of them?

Comment: Obviously, using two different encodings. Do you know encoding of particular file before reading it, or you need some way to detect it?

Comment: I was thinking about something like an if instruction. If the encoding of the xml is iso-8859-1: var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), else ...

Comment: ...OK? So write some code that does that. I don't see what the question is here.

Comment: I don't know how. That's the question ;). I'm a very beginner in c#

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `FileStream` instead of a `StreamReader`. The `XmlSerializer` internally will create an `XmlTextReader` that will detect the encoding.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));

using (var fs = new FileStream(current_file, FileMode.Open))
{
    var i = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

To check which encoding is being used:

```
Element el1;
Encoding enc1;

using (var fs = new FileStream("Text1252.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(fs))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    enc1 = reader.Encoding;
    el1 = (Element)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: That works when encoding is Windows-1252 but nor for iso-8859-1

Comment: @AnneMartin Is the encoding specified in the file? Like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1">`?

Comment: yes, it is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: @AnneMartin The difference in iso-8859-1 and windows-1252 is only in some unprintable control characters that are present in iso-8859-1 but replaced in windows-1252 with `€, ™` and others. If both files are read as windows-1252 there should be no problem. There could be a problem if the files are uncorrectly encoded, for example by prepending an UTF-8 BOM. Posted some code to check the encoding it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer [obtaining the xml encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293196/obtaining-the-xml-encoding-from-an-xml-declaration-fragment-xmldeclaration-is-n) will be helpful to get encoding.
When you deserialize it you can use something similar to below;

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string objectXml, Encoding encoding)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToByteArray(objectXml, encoding));
        T deserializedObject = (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        return deserializedObject;
    }
```