# Saving and loading different windows forms at run time in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I built my windows form app in visual studio and on desktop it looks fine. Although when I put it up on a projector we found the fonts etc were a bit small.

So what I want to do is using the designer design two versions of the app one the normal version I have now (Desktop Version) and another one with larger buttons and fonts (presentation version).

Then on runtime I want the user to be able to choose between the desktop and presentation versions of the app.

I'm a little unsure how to do this though, is it possible to save and load various different designs in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your other form as a new one. Then simply call `Hide()` and `Show()` to switch between forms.
Another option is to export your design to some sort of data (xml, json, even plain text could work) and once form is resized and if size if greater than something, then swap styles of your controls.

Points of interest:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/
- [encoding xml for deserialization in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188323/encoding-xml-for-deserialization-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: Glad to help you