# How to get encoding of xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, serialization, encoding

How to get the information of encoding in a xml file using c#?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```

I know how to read in the elements and attributes... 
But I have to make a definition by cases in my deserialization method:
Depending on the encoding type of the xml I have to use encoding_windows or encoding_utf for StreamReader

```
var encoding_windows = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
var encoding_utf = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
var sr = new StreamReader(current_file, encoding_windows, true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining the XML encoding from an XML declaration fragment: XmlDeclaration is not supported for partial content parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293196/obtaining-the-xml-encoding-from-an-xml-declaration-fragment-xmldeclaration-is-n)

Comment: Is this something you need to know because you want to write the file in the same encoding as reading it, or is there some other reason you want to know?

Comment: I need to know the encoding for deserialization method

Comment: I think you are wrong.  The encoding type is a hint to the deserialisation library as to how the information was encoded.  You shouldn't need to know that information for that reason.  The fields should all be presented to you after deserialisation in .net terms (int, string etc).  How they got decoded should be irrelevant (assuming you are using a good .net library).

Answer (score 2):

As your are using **StreamReader** try this :

```
var sr = new StreamReader(current_file);

var encodingCurrentFile = sr.CurrentEncoding.EncodingName;

Console.WriteLine(encodingCurrentFile);
```

**encodingCurrentFile** is your current encoding name.