# Split one xml file to multiple using c#

Tags: c#, xml, single-file

I am getting XML data in single file for multiple records.

If i open this file using XMLDocument it is saying unrecognized format.

Is there a better way to read this file and process as each record.

below is the XML Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE NAXML-FuelsDoc SYSTEM "NAXML-FuelsDoc.dtd">
<NAXML-FuelsDoc version="1.0">
<TransmissionHeader>
<TransmissionId>616805428</TransmissionId>
<TransmissionDate>20171201</TransmissionDate>
<TransmissionTime>093100</TransmissionTime>
<TransmissionStatus actionType="original"/>
<TransmissionSender>Coffeyville Resources Refining Marketing</TransmissionSender>
<TransmissionReceiver>Desert Fuels Inc.</TransmissionReceiver>
<TransmissionAgency>DTN Energy Integrated Services/dtnDataConnect</TransmissionAgency>
</TransmissionHeader>
</NAXML-FuelsDoc>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE NAXML-FuelsDoc SYSTEM "NAXML-FuelsDoc.dtd">
<NAXML-FuelsDoc version="1.0">
<TransmissionHeader>
<TransmissionId>43234997</TransmissionId>
<TransmissionDate>20171201</TransmissionDate>
<TransmissionTime>093100</TransmissionTime>
<TransmissionStatus actionType="original"/>
<TransmissionSender>Coffeyville Resources Refining Marketing</TransmissionSender>
<TransmissionReceiver>Desert Fuels Inc.</TransmissionReceiver>
<TransmissionAgency>DTN Energy Integrated Services/dtnDataConnect</TransmissionAgency>
</TransmissionHeader>
</NAXML-FuelsDoc>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE NAXML-FuelsDoc SYSTEM "NAXML-FuelsDoc.dtd">
<NAXML-FuelsDoc version="1.0">
<TransmissionHeader>
<TransmissionId>54356923</TransmissionId>
<TransmissionDate>20171201</TransmissionDate>
<TransmissionTime>093100</TransmissionTime>
<TransmissionStatus actionType="original"/>
<TransmissionSender>Coffeyville Resources Refining Marketing</TransmissionSender>
<TransmissionReceiver>Desert Fuels Inc.</TransmissionReceiver>
<TransmissionAgency>DTN Energy Integrated Services/dtnDataConnect</TransmissionAgency>
</TransmissionHeader>
</NAXML-FuelsDoc>
```

Comment: That’s not valid XML so it’s right to refuse it. You’ll have to split it yourself into proper sections which isn’t difficult since there’s a clear starting point with xml declaration line

Comment: If linked duplicate is not enough search terms to use https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+xml+fragment, after getting good understanding of what you are looking for [edit] post to clarify why approaches suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038663/read-a-fake-xml-document-xml-fragment-in-a-xmltextreader-object do not work for you so question can be potentially re-opened.

Comment: I will get 100's of records like this, splitting manually is a painful job.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for your help.